# Javascript window.location calls getting lost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, window.location

I am having some trouble with a bit of code.  I have a function that does some stuff to some data, calls a remote system (activating a script on that system and passing in the data), and then makes another call to the same system to activate a different script (which acts on the data saved above).  The problem is that the 1st call to the remote system appears to get lost in the execution.

This is being run in Safari, uses jquery; the function is tied to a button click, which is defined in the javascript code with an onclick function (i.e. it is not defined in the html button definition).

Here's a rough breakdown of the function (cleaned out for viewing purposes - I hope I left enough to make it clear):

```
function compareJSON() {
    // loop through the objects, testing and changing data
    //  ...

    dataSession=({ //build object for output    });   

    $.each( dataSession.chapters , function( indexC, value ) {  
        //compare objects to some others, testing and changing data
    });

    //  ...

    //Call remote script on other system
    urlString="url://blah.dee.com/Blar?script=SaveJSON&$JSONobject=";
    window.location= urlString + JSON.stringify(dataSession);

   //Call remote script on other system
   window.location="url://blah.dee.com/Blar?script=EditJSON";
}
```

The last three lines of code are the two calls.  It uses the window.location to actually trigger the remote system, passing the data through the URL.  But I need BOTH scripts to get called and run.  It appears that only the LAST script in the sequence ever gets run.  If I switch them around it remains whatever is in last place.

Is there something about the window.location that doesn't actually process until the end of the function?

This script actually used to be a series of separate function calls, but I figured I was running into asynchronous execution that was causing the various script calls to not register.  But once I put the code into this single function, it was still happening.

Any clues would be helpful.

Thanks,
J

Comment: are you loading a different page into the window

Comment: anyway this method will not be reliable since there will be any assurance that the first call is completed before the second one is sent.... you may want to have a look at AJAX...

Comment: if your page is loacated in a different domain then you may have to look at CORS/JSONP

Comment: Arun:  unfortunately, some 'normal' web technologies aren't available:  PHP, AJAX, etc.  This setting of the location, causing a semi-redirect, seems to be our only recourse (at least that we have figured out).    Frankly, it is not important if the first call is finished before the second is made as the target system just adds it to it's own stack and it gets executed in order.  It is HIGHLY important that BOTH calls get made, though.  I just thought it was strange that only one was getting made.

Answer (score 0):

Modifing the value of `window.location` is reserved exclusively for instances in which you'd like to cause a browser redirect.

It looks like you want to trigger a page request instead. You say you already have jQuery loaded, if so, you can trigger such a request using [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get) or a similar function.

For example:

```
// Loads the myscript.php page in the background
$.get('myscript.php');

// You can also pass data (in the form of an object as the second argument)
$.get('myscript.php', { name: "John", time: "2pm" });
```

Comment: Jacob:  Yes, we are using the browser redirect to cause the server to trigger the script.  I will see if we perhaps can get this to work; it sticks in my mind that we tried this in the past and ran into technological problems.  This is not exactly a full blown web/internet environment, with all the available niceties.  This is a web viewer inside of a FileMaker DB solution.

Comment: Oh, I should clarify that since it is a FileMaker web viewer the URL call is actually NOT using HTTP, but FMP as the protocol (thus it gets sent to the FileMaker server to handle and thus call the script).

Comment: Yeah, when I try $.get() I get this error:  Failed to load resource: unsupported URL.  The URL I am using is like this:  "fmp://server.spot.com/..."  FMP is registered on my system but it appears that .get doesn't like it.

Comment: It looks like the Window.Location isn't being finalized/set/sent/whatever until the ENTIRE JS call stack is finished.  So, when I click the button the script call stack gets two 'handler' related scripts added to it before hitting the JS code that I wrote, which in turn add a few more function calls to the stack.  It is in this series of calls that the 'window.location' gets updated.  But these calls don't actually trigger the remote system until I step all the way through the JS call stack and exit the original function.  Is there a way to force window.location to be evaluated?